# Alfresco 4.2e LDAP AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, alfresco, bitnami

I have to connect to LDAP AD server from Alfresco 4.2e which is on Bitnami. Initially i am just trying for authentication part and not the synchronization part.

I updated the alfresco-global.properties

```
authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap-ad
```

I created the directory structure /shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Authentication/ldap-ad/ldap1/

and added the authentication properties in it. I have set the

```
ldap.sychronization.active=false
```

Still i am unable to login with LDAP users. I noticed the log part. It is not showing the starting and startup complete logs for LDAP Authentication. It shows only for NTLM part.

Please help as i am not an Alfresco person and i am given this task :( . So please Alfesco experts let me know if i am missing anything. I think before i check whether authentication details are proper, there should be entry in log file regarding starting LDAP authentication subsystem and any error thereafter. Am i correct?

```
2014-03-20 12:57:10,392  INFO  [domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1]   No changes were made to the schema.
2014-03-20 12:57:12,072  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory]   [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2014-03-20 12:57:12,562  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
2014-03-20 12:57:13,214  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Search' subsystem, ID: [Search, managed, lucene]
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

You can set all the needed properties in alfresco-global.properties and don't need to override the extension structure.

Second:
Have you followed this(comes from the alfresco 4.2.x community [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/topic/com.alfresco.community.doc/concepts/community-videos-14.html)):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQjkEh1AuAk#t=213

I personally think you miss all the required properties.

Comment: I have gone thru this and other blogs and documentation. I have done steps as per the video. Still not able to login. My main concern is the log file part. I think the ldap authentication subsystem logs should be shown like alfrescoNtlm is shown in logs.

Comment: You can also put all the properties in the alfresco-global.properties and remove the extension/subsystems/....